# App crashes with in-app purchase error

Tags: ios, swift

I use this code to create my in-app purchase:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate {

var product_id: String?
@IBOutlet weak var buyButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    product_id = "product_id"

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
}

 @IBAction func unlockAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("About to fetch the product...")

    // Can make payments
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
    {
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
        let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        productsRequest.start();
        print("Fetching Products");
    }else{
        print("Can't make purchases");
    }

}

func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment);

}

func productsRequest (_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

    let count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {
        let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            buyProduct(product: validProduct);

        } else {
            print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    } else {
        print("nothing")
    }
}
```

But if I click on button(unlockAction) twice or click once, move on different controller, return and click once more my app crashes on this line:

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment);
```

with error `(lldb)`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `viewWillDissappear()` function for that in your billing controller. Try that one .

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
}
```

I was also getting that problem and that has been resolve my problem.

> The error was with `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)` line in the code. So try this solution and be reliable productive programmer. 
>   **Happy Coding**

Comment: if i delete this line `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)` in `viewDidLoad()` it is also solve problem. Is this way correct?

Comment: No because `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)`  it connect your payment method in-App-Purchase pop up... Means this provide the complete working to you so it's necessary while your load so that you didn't get any mistake when your application goes live..

Comment: It’s strange. If I delete line `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)` my in app purchase is working fine.

Comment: I save this line `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment);` in `func buyProduct(product: SKProduct)`.

Comment: then it's ok you can continue with that